# Real memory usage - MPFlipTransition

Tags: ios, ipad, memory, memory-management, uiimageview

I am creating an app with an `UIViewController` which displays other `UIViewControllers` with the `MPFlipTransition` inside it. It's like a little book on iPad.
The `UIViewControllers` inside are created each with xibs with 4-5 `UIImageViews` inside and some of those images are animated with CoreAnimations (`[UIView animateWithDuration]` blocks)
I remove all the animations in the `viewDidDiseappear` function with the QuartzCore function removeAllAnimation on each animated layer.
But when I'm testing the app on an iPad 3, it works properly, but on iPad 2 it crashes at about the 8th page change.
I've made a profiling with Instruments and found that the real memory usage was increasing everytime I turned the page (when the `MPFlipTransition` appears). But even if I remove from the superview the previous views, the real memory usage is not decreasing. I thinks that it created the crash on the iPad 2 because the crash come when the real memory usage is passing the 400 Mbytes value (and the iPad 2 has only 512MB...).

What do you think about this problem ? Any help ? I'm using ARC for memory management...
Thanks for you help ! Feel free to ask if any need of precisions...

Comment: In fact I tried to init the UIImageView not via the XIB, with the imageWithContentsOfFile and it works. It's a problem of caching...